# Ubuntu: hadoop command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to check my installation of hadoop. I did create the environment variables and when I call `printenv`, I do see my HADOOP_HOME and PATH variables printed and correct (home/hadoop and HADOOP_HOME/bin respectively).

If I go to home/hadoop in the terminal and call `ls`, I see the hadoop file there. If I try to run it by calling `hadoop`, it still tells me command not found.

First day on Linux, so there may be a stupid answer to this problem.

Comment: Please show **exactly** what you get from printenv, because both things you've posted are wrong as written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current working directory is probably not part of your path.
That is default on linux systems.

If you are in the same directory, where your `hadoop` file is, run that command with an relative path, like: `./hadoop`

Comment: When I extracted the hadoop zipped file, there were no file under the name `hadoop`. I downloaded the version 2.6.0

Answer (score 5):

**HOME DIRECTORY:**

**/home/hadoop** is a home directory created by linux similar to `Document and settings` in windows.

Open your terminal and type:

```
ls -l /home/hadoop
```

> Post your result for this command: **ls -l /home/hadoop**

**SETTING GLOBAL PATH:**

Go to `/home/hadoop` and open `.bashrc` in text editor.
Add these lines at the end:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/your/hadoop/installation/folder
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Save and exit. Now type, this in your teminal:

```
echo $PATH
echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

If these commands shows correct directories, try `hadoop` command. It should work.

> Post your result for these command: **echo $PATH** and **echo $HADOOP_HOME**

Comment: I am just trying to set up hadoop on my ubuntu machine and I was following this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mahout/mahout_environment.htm) tutorial. After modifying the configuration files mentioned in the tutorial, when I run `hadoop version` it still gives me `hadoop: command not found`. 
The results for the commands posted in this answer are in the following comment.

Comment: `ls -l /home/hadoop`

`total 44`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Desktop`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Documents`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Downloads`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 8980 ජන 7 13:19 examples.desktop`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Music`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Pictures`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Public`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Templates`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 ජන 7 13:20 Videos`

Comment: `echo $PATH`
`/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin`

`echo $HADOOP_HOME`
`/usr/local/hadoop`

Comment: Post the result for `ls -l /usr/local/hadoop/bin` and `ls -l /usr/local/hadoop/sbin`

Comment: `bin` is not found.
`sbin` has these
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2752 19:46 distribute-exclude.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6452 19:46 hadoop-daemon.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1360 19:46 hadoop-daemons.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1640 19:46 hdfs-config.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1427 19:46 hdfs-config.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2291 19:46 httpfs.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2059 19:46 kms.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4080 19:46 mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh`

Comment: and these
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1648 19:46 refresh-namenodes.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2145 19:46 slaves.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1779 19:46 start-all.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1471 19:46 start-all.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1128 19:46 start-balancer.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1401 19:46 start-dfs.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3705 19:46 start-dfs.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1357 19:46 start-secure-dns.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1571 19:46 start-yarn.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1347 19:46 start-yarn.sh`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1770 19:46 stop-all.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1462 19:46 stop-all.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1179 19:46 stop-balancer.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1455 19:46 stop-dfs.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3206 19:46 stop-dfs.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1340 19:46 stop-secure-dns.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1642 19:46 stop-yarn.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1340 19:46 stop-yarn.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4295 19:46 yarn-daemon.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1353 19:46 yarn-daemons.sh`

Comment: All these files should be owned by `hadoop` user and not `root` user. Change the ownership of hadoop folder first and then try `hadoop` command. It should work. Try this in terminal: `sudo chown -R hadoopusername:hadoopgroupname /usr/local/hadoop`... Note: If it asks for password, enter your root password and change whatever you have given for hadoop username and groupname respectively.

Comment: If you haven't created hadoop group and user, please read `Adding dedicated hadoop system user` section in http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: I tried it and changed ownership. (partial content of the folder is shown below)

`-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop-ranji hadoop 2752 ජන    7 19:46 distribute-exclude.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop-ranji hadoop 6452 ජන    7 19:46 hadoop-daemon.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop-ranji hadoop 1360 ජන    7 19:46 hadoop-daemons.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop-ranji hadoop 1640 ජන    7 19:46 hdfs-config.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop-ranji hadoop 1427 ජන    7 19:46 hdfs-config.sh
`
But still the hadoop command does not work. 

`hadoop: command not found`

Comment: Did you try `hadoop` command as `hadoop-ranji` user? If you have executed hadoop command as `hadoop-ranji` user and still get commad not found, then try this `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/hadoop`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it as `hadoop-ranji` user and after changing permissions, still I am getting `command not found`

Comment: I assume your hadoop installation folder does not have `bin` folder. If so, try downloading it again from https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz . Not the `hadoop-2.6.0-src.tar.gz` one.

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, my installation did not have the `bin` folder. The download you mentioned worked I guess. I don't get the `hadoop: command not` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Hadoop-x.x.x/bin folder
2. check for hadoop folder there
3. run ./hadoop version

Answer (score 1):

You must run “`hadoop version`” command.

If the hadoop setup is fine, then you should see the following result:

```
Hadoop 2.4.1 
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768 
Compiled by hortonmu on 2013-10-07T06:28Z 
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 79e53ce7994d1628b240f09af91e1af4
```

For installation related guide you can refer here:

[Hadoop Environment Setup](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm)

Link to my quora answer https://qr.ae/TWngHN

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enter `which hadoop` in your terminal. If you see a path as an output, hadoop is set in PATH of your system. If you get something similar to this,
`usr/bin/which: no hadoop in (/usr/local/hadoop....` you might not have setup everything properly. Modify the `/etc/bash.bashrc` with 
`export HADOOP_HOME = /path/to/hadoop/folder` and add it to PATH using `export PATH=$PATH:HADOOP_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You may be editing the wrong ~/.bashrc file.

Open terminal and run `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` and edit these command

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

Note: You must not use `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc.sh` these both work differently on newer OS